# The equivalent to using __proto__?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, revealing-module-pattern

I'm trying to use the revealing module pattern with inheritance. I seem to have it working fine, but it uses "__proto__", which I understand it's considered deprecated. Is there a better was to create the inheritance with out using "__proto__"?

```
var Person = (function() {
    var _name;
    var api = {
        init: init,
        getName: getName
    }
    return api;

    function init(name) {
        _name = name;
    }

    function getName() {
        return _name;
    }
}())

var Teacher = (function() {
    var _subject = "Math";
    var api = {
        getSubject: getSubject,
        say: say
    }
    api.__proto__ = Person;
    return api;

    function getSubject() {
        return _subject;
    }

    function say() {
        console.log("I am " + this.getName() + " and I teach " + _subject)
    }
}());

Teacher.init("Bob");
Teacher.say() //  I am Bob and I teach math
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/XbGx38oCyvRn79xnn2FR?p=preview

Comment: I don't see why you need to set the prototype chain after creating the object when `Object.create` lets you set it at creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct equivalent – setting the prototype, still a bad idea – is `Object.setPrototypeOf`:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(api, Person);
```

The normal way of creating an object based on a prototype with `Object.create` and then adding properties to it works fine here, though:

```
var api = Object.create(Person);
api.getSubject = getSubject;
api.say = say;
```

but ideally you would just use constructors:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    getName() {
        return this._name;
    }
}

class Teacher extends Person {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name);
        this._subject = 'Math';
    }

    getSubject() {
        return this._subject;
    }

    say() {
        console.log(`I am ${this.getName()} and I teach ${this.getSubject()}`);
    }
}

var teacher = new Teacher('Bob');
teacher.say() //  I am Bob and I teach math
```

without ES6:

```
function Person(name) {
    this._name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this._name;
};

function Teacher(name) {
    Person.call(this, name);
    this._subject = 'Math';
}

Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

Teacher.prototype.getSubject = function () {
    return this._subject;
};

Teacher.prototype.say = function () {
    console.log('I am ' + this.getName() + ' and I teach ' + this.getSubject());
};

var teacher = new Teacher('Bob');
teacher.say();  // I am Bob and I teach math
```

Comment: JS6 unfortunately isn't an option, but Object.create() did the trick - with a little help from jquery: 

 $.extend(api, Object.create(Person));

Comment: @Skyler: Why would you need `$.extend` there? Anyway, you don’t have to use ES6 classes to use constructors; see edit.

Comment: I like to define my public methods in an api object at the top of the code block. So I then use $.extend to combine it with the base object.